# Routes on the server do not work (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

how are you?

Well, while my system was operating locally my routes worked very well.
The problem started when I went to test the system on the server.

I have a form that calls a route to update the database and then it redirects to a view.

My url of the form is this way, "http://myserver/SisPrev/salvarefetivoum" after saving the data she goes to this url, "http://myserver/conjuge/addBanco", losing the /SisPrev reference.

Could anyone tell me why he does this?

My route:

```
Route::post('/conjuge/addBanco', 'ViewController@adicionarConjuge');
```

Part of my blade:

```
<form role="form" method='post' action='/conjuge/addBanco' autocomplete="off">
```

Part of my controller that returns to the view that is not being able to access:

```
$user = Usuario::where('nr_cpf_servidor',$cpf)->first();

if($user == null){
   return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Não foi possível encontrar o Servidor.']);
}else{
   return view('/endereco_edit', compact('user','logradouros'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing but what I’ll advise is to give names to your routes like this

```
Route::post('/conjuge/addBanco', 'ViewController@adicionarConjuge')->name(‘adicionarConjuge’);
```

And call them using the name eg

```
<form role="form" method='post' action='{{route(‘adicionarConjuge’)}}' autocomplete="off">
```

And redirect using the route names too eg

```
redirect()->route(‘adicionarConjuge’);
```